# Generating a complex xls file from a complex dictionary in django

Tags: python, django, xls, xlwt

I have a dictionary structured like this.

```
data_dict = {'man_id':{'news_name_one':
                             'zc_one':{'id':2, 'name': 'nameone', 'adrs':'adrsone',      'state':'stateone'} 
                             'zc_two':{'id':3, 'name': 'nametwo', 'adrs':'adrstwo', 'state':'statetwo'}  
                             'zc_three':{'id':4, 'name': 'namethree', 'adrs':'adrsthree', 'state':'statethree'}    
                      },
                      {'news_name_two':
                             'zc_one':{'id':2, 'name': 'namefour', 'adrs':'adrsfour', 'state':'statefour'} 
                             'zc_two':{'id':3, 'name': 'namefive', 'adrs':'adrsfive', 'state':'statefive'}  
                             'zc_three':{'id':4, 'name': 'namesix', 'adrs':'adrssix', 'state':'statesix'}    
                      }
            }
```

Now i have to generate an complex xls file in python/django. The format of the xls file can be found here." http://ge.tt/4B7xfQX ". How can it be done. I am also trying to do it in a html page. But too much confused.

Comment: Looks like you've muddled up your posting of `data_dict`: do a `from pprint import pprint; pprint(data_dict)` and post the result of that, making sure it's all in a codeblock

Comment: please make your question self contained and add the xml output you would like to have.

Comment: Hi root, I have uploaded the sample xls file and share d the link above.

Comment: easy solution will be make xml file of that dict which obeys `Microsoft Office XML formats` with elementTree!   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example

Comment: As @JonClements wrote, your input is stuffed ... `SyntaxError` at the first `:` in `zc_one':{'id':2,`. Also your link to your format looks sufficiently dodgy to make one wary. Try making it a bit easier for people to answer your question.